# Can SDL2 render and use svg files easily? Would an svg file work well for the board of a board game?

Tags: c++, svg

I have seen a few other posts talking about how using svgs can be very slow, but would it be the right thing to use for a board game for when I want it to be possible to zoom in and out? The other assets would be pngs but would it make sense for the board to be an svg? And would I need other libraries to do this, or would SDL2 work just fine by it self?

Comment: Since SVG is a vector format, the time it takes to render and SVG depends on how much detail is present in the SVG.  If you have an SVG that is slow to render, one trick is to render it just once into a bitmap at the desired size and use that instead of always rendering from the SVG directly; that way the number of times you need to re-render the SVG can be greatly reduced.

Comment: Can you post the links to posts stating SVGs are slow. They aren't, all cases I have seen are programmers not understanding the technology.. like stuffing 9 digit decimal precision into 1 "pixel"